# Как найти высоту от хорды до дуги для любой точки хорды?

Tags: геометрия

Есть хорда окружности, требуется найти высоту до окружности от любой точки хорды.
Есть формулы для высоты от хорды до окружности из центра хорды, но никак не могу сообразить как считать для любой точки хорды.

Comment: Как вы задаёте точку на хорде? Каким параметром?

Comment: Мне нужно последовательно идя по хорде в заданным шагом посчитать все высоты до окружности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окружность радиуса R, хорда с центральным углом 2α, на хорде задан параметр t ∈ [-1, 1] (0 - середина хорды). Тогда высота над хордой в точке t равна

> H(t) = R[√(1 - t<sup>2</sup>sin<sup>2</sup>α) - cosα], t ∈ [-1, 1]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Формула отлично считает!

Answer (score 0):

```
h = R*(Cos(fi)-Cos(alpha/2))
```

где `fi` - угол отклонения ***от центра дуги***, `alpha` - центральный угол дуги

Answer (score 0):

Перенесем начало координат в центр окружности. Пусть (x2,y2) - радиус вектор одного края хорды. (x0,y0) - радиус вектор точки на хорде откуда идет перпендикуляр до окружности. (x,y) - радиус вектор точки пересечения перпендикуляра с окружностью (их две), h - искомая высота, R - радиус окружности. Тогда используя теорему Пифагора для треугольника (x0,y0)-(x,y)-(x2,y2) получаем систему из трех уравнений.

```
(1) (x-x2)^2+(y-y2)^2=(x0-x2)^2+(y0-y2)^2+h^2;
(2) x^2+y^2=R^2;
(3) (x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2=h^2;
```

...
3 уравнения, три неизвестные - h,x,y. Решаем и получаем достаточно громоздкие формулы. Приведу их, надеюсь не накосячил..

```
h^2=(p-y*t-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2;
где 
t=(y0-y2)/(x0-x2);
p=(x0^2+y0^2-x0*x2-y0*y2)/(x0-x2);
y=(p*t+-\sqrt{R^2(t^2+1)-p^2})/(t^2+1);
```

находим два значения y, до ближайшей дуги и до дальней. До ближайшей будет меньшее значение.
Далее пусть хорда задается своим начальным (x2,y2) и конечным(x1,y1) значениями. Надо перебрать все возможные (x0,y0). Если поделить хорду на n частей то формула для (x0,y0) следующая

```
(x2+(k/n)*(x1-x2),y2+(k/n)*(y1-y2))
```

где k-целое пробегает значение от 1 до n-1. И в каждом таком (x0,y0) вычисляем h по вышеописанным формулам.